# please help really stuck on structures

Tags: c

<strike>hi guys been using this site for a while now for tips but never posted before (first time for everything i suppose) anyway doing an assignment for college (Manufacturing degree) so probably basic to some of you. basically</strike>

the problem is in the search by student name void near the bottom the program runs but crashes as soon as i enter the name <strike>any help would be really appreciated</strike>

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 2

struct Student
{
    long StudentID;//works
    char fname[21];//works
    char sname[21];//does not work
    int year;//works
    char course[51];//works
    float results_semester_1[6];//works
    float results_semester_2[6];//works
    int free;  // 1 means its free, 0 means its not
};

struct Student BENG[SIZE];

int menu();   // function prototype
void add_student();  // function prototype
void display_students(); // function prototype
void display_results(); // function prototype
void search_for_student_studentID(); // function prototype
void search_for_student_by_name(); // function prototype
void delete_student(); // function prototype
void initialise_database(); // function prototype
void Run_statistics_for_individual_student(); // function prototype
void Run_statistics_for_all_student(); // function prototype
int linear_search(long); // function prototype
int linear_search_sname(char); // function prototype


int main()
{

    initialise_database();  // call the function to set all free positions to 1

    for(;;)  // infinite loop
    {
        switch(menu())   // calling function menu within switch
        {
            case 1:
                add_student();  // calling function add_student
                break;
            case 2:
                delete_student();  // calling function delete_student
                break;
            case 3:
                display_students(); // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 4:
                search_for_student_studentID();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 5:
                search_for_student_by_name();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 6:
                Run_statistics_for_individual_student();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 7:
                Run_statistics_for_all_student();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 8:
                display_results();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("Quitting Program\n");
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Invalid option chosen\n\n");
        }
    }  // end of infinite loop

    return 0;
}

void add_student()
{
    int freepos = -1, i, j,k,year;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(BENG[i].free == 1)
        {
            freepos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(freepos != -1)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Enter student ID:\n");
            scanf("%ld", &BENG[freepos].StudentID);
        }
        while(BENG[freepos].StudentID<10000000 ||BENG[freepos].StudentID>99999999);

        printf("Enter firstname:\n");
        scanf("%s", BENG[freepos].fname);

        printf("Enter surname:\n");
        scanf("%s", BENG[freepos].sname);

        do
        {
            printf("Enter year of course:\n");
            scanf("%d", &BENG[freepos].year);
        }
        while(BENG[freepos].year < 1 || BENG[freepos].year > 4);

        printf("Enter course name:\n");
        scanf("%s", BENG[freepos].course);

        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter result of semester 1  Module %d:\n", j+1);
            scanf("%f", &BENG[freepos].results_semester_1[j]);
        }
        for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            printf("Enter result of semester 2  Module %d:\n", k+1);
            scanf("%f", &BENG[freepos].results_semester_2[k]);
        }

        BENG[freepos].free = 0;  // mark record as taken
    }
    else
        printf("No position free at present\n");
}

void display_students()
{
    // output the values just entered
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
        {
            printf("Student ID: %ld:\n", BENG[i].StudentID);
            printf("Firstname: %s\n", BENG[i].fname);
            printf("Surname: %s\n", BENG[i].sname);
            printf("Year: %d\n", BENG[i].year);
            printf("Course: %s\n", BENG[i].course);
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_1[j]);
            }  // end of for
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_2[j]);
            }  // end of for
        }  // end of if
    }  // end of for
}
void display_results()
{
    // output the values just entered
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_1[j]);
            }  // end of for
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_2[j]);
            }  // end of for
        }  // end of if
    }  // end of for
}
int menu()
{
    int choice;
    printf("1. To add a student\n");
    printf("2. To delete a student\n");
    printf("3. To display all students\n");
    printf("4. Find a student using studentID\n");
    printf("5. Find a student by student Surname\n");
    printf("6. Find student would you like to run statistics for\n");
    printf("7. Find statistics for all students\n");
    printf("8. Display results of all students\n");
    printf("9. Exit Program\n");

    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    while(choice < 1 || choice > 9);

    return choice;
}

void initialise_database()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) // set all structure variables free to 1
        BENG[i].free = 1;
}

void delete_student()
{
    long search;
    int position,freepos;

    printf("Enter the number of student to delete\n");
    scanf("%ld",&search);

    position = linear_search(search);

    if ( position == -1 )
        printf("%d is not present in array.\n", search);
    else
        printf("%d is present at location %d.\n", search, position+1);
    BENG[position].free = 1;
    return;
}

void search_for_student_studentID()
{
    long search;
    int position,j,i;

    printf("Enter the number to search\n");
    scanf("%ld",&search);

    position = linear_search(search);

    if ( position == -1 )
        printf("%d is not present in array.\n", search);
    else
        printf("%d is present at location %d.\n", search, position+1);
    printf("Student ID: %ld:\n", BENG[position].StudentID);
    printf("Firstname: %s\n", BENG[position].fname);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", BENG[position].sname);
    printf("Year: %d\n", BENG[position].year);
    printf("Course: %s\n", BENG[position].course);
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1,         BENG[i].results_semester_1[j]);
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_2[j]);
    }
    return;
}

void search_for_student_by_name(sname)
{
    int position,j,i;

    printf("Enter the surname of student to search\n");
    scanf("%s",&sname);

    position = linear_search_sname(sname);

    if ( position == 1 )
        printf("%s is not present in array.\n", sname);
    else
        printf("%s is present at location %d.\n", sname, position+1);
    printf("Student ID: %ld:\n", BENG[position].StudentID);
    printf("Firstname: %s\n", BENG[position].fname);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", BENG[position].sname);
    printf("Year: %d\n", BENG[position].year);
    printf("Course: %s\n", BENG[position].course);
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_1[j]);
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_2[j]);
    }

    return;
}
int linear_search(long find)
{
    int c;

    for ( c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++ )
    {
        if (BENG[c].StudentID == find )
        {
            return c;
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int linear_search_sname(char find)
{
    int c;

    for ( c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++ )
    {
        if (BENG[c].sname[21] == find )
        {
            return c;
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
void Run_statistics_for_individual_student()
{
    long search;
    int position,j,i,k,r,max,minsums,min=100;
    float sums = 0,maxsums=0;

    printf("Enter the number to search\n");
    scanf("%ld",&search);
    printf("The statistics for student ID:\n",search);

    position = linear_search(search);

    if ( position == -1 )
        printf("%d is not present in array.\n", search);
    else

        for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            sums += BENG[position].results_semester_1[i];
        }
    printf("Average grade over 6 subjects for this student in semester 1 is %0.2f marks\n",    sums/6);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        maxsums = BENG[position].results_semester_1[i];
    }
    if(maxsums>max)
    {
        max=maxsums;
    }   // end of if

    printf("Max grade for this student in semester 1 is %d\n", max);
    {

        for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            if(BENG[position].results_semester_1[k]<min)    
            {
                min=BENG[position].results_semester_1[k];
            }   // end of if    
        }// end of for
        printf("Min grade for this student in semester 2 is %d\n", min);    
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        sums += BENG[position].results_semester_2[i];           
    }
    printf("Average grade over 6 subjects for this student in semester 2 is %0.2f marks\n",  sums/6);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        maxsums = BENG[position].results_semester_2[i];  
    }   
    if(maxsums>max)     
    {
        max=maxsums;
    }   // end of if        

    printf("Max grade for this student in semester 2 is %d\n", max);    
    {

        for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            if(BENG[position].results_semester_2[k]<min)    
            {
                min=BENG[position].results_semester_2[k];
            }   // end of if    
        }// end of for
        printf("Min grade for this student in semester 2 is %d\n", min);    
    }
    return ;
}

void Run_statistics_for_all_student()
{

    // output the values just entered
    int i,j,k, max,min=100;
    float sums,maxsums=0;
    {
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

            if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    {
                        sums += BENG[i].results_semester_1[i];              
                    } // end of for

                }  // end of for

            }  // end of if

        printf("Average grade for all students in semester 1 is %0.2f \n", sums/(SIZE*6)); 
    }               
    {
        for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)

            if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    {
                        maxsums = BENG[i].results_semester_1[i];  
                    }   
                    if(maxsums>max)     
                    {
                        max=maxsums;
                    }       
                }// end of for
            }// end of if
    }
    printf("Max grade for all student in semester 1 is%d\n", max);  

    {
        for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)

            if(BENG[k].free == 0) // only print taken records
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        if(BENG[i].results_semester_1[i]<min)   
                        {
                            min=BENG[i].results_semester_1[i];
                        }       
                    }// end of for
                }// end of for
            }// end of if
    }
    printf("Min grade for all student in semester 1 is %d\n", min);


    return ;
}
```

Comment: Could you prepare a small (yet compilable) version of this that just includes the necessary elements to reproduce the problem?

Comment: ...and please indent you code blocks.

Comment: I also do see so many oddities that I don't know where to start. For example, you have an else that is meant to embrace a sequence of statements but I think you forgot to put curly braces, so all the statements after the first are boldly executed no matter what. Try to break things down.

Comment: Something that will really help: add the `-Wall` flag when you compile. This will show all warnings the compiler knows about.

Comment: @nanny how do i do a -Wall flag im using DEV

Comment: @simonp Dev-C++? I really don't know, sorry. Check the documentation for your IDE.

Comment: @simonp You must enable **warnings** when you compile. `-Wall -Wextra` at minimum. I just compiled your code and got some 80 lines containing some 18 warnings. You cannot expect to get good results back from your code until you address each of the warnings. Code should compile without warnings for you to have confidence it will produce the desired results. While it is fine to use an `IDE`, I would also recommend compiling by hand in a terminal window to really learn what your `IDE` is doing for you. (it's actually easier by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a large number of errors throughout your code. All of them due to **NOT SLOWING DOWN AND THINKING ABOUT EACH LINE (and part of each line)**. C is an **exact** language. That is one of its strengths. There is no such thing as **close enough** in either syntax or logic. One way to find most of these **...oversights...** is to compile with **warnings** turned on. A compile string for your program should at a minimum contain `-Wall -Wextra`. For example:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o student_database student_database.c
```

That will catch most of your basic syntax and variable type mismatch problems. Eliminate **each and every** warning. The compiler didn't accidentally throw them. They mean something.

That being said, I have eliminated the warnings in your code. I have been through the `add_student` function to the extent that it will accept input and prevent `newlines` from remaining in the input buffer prior to the next entry. I have corrected other areas just to the extent to resolve the compiler warnings. Your code **still needs lots of work**. This will give you a good start and eliminate that overwhelmed feeling (for the time being). Work through your code, look at the corrections I've made. Slow down -- and you will do fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 4

struct Student
{
    long StudentID;//works
    char fname[21];//works
    char sname[21];//does not work
    int year;//works
    char course[51];//works
    float results_semester_1[6];//works
    float results_semester_2[6];//works
    int free;  // 1 means its free, 0 means its not
};

struct Student BENG[SIZE];

int menu();   // function prototype
void add_student();  // function prototype
void display_students(); // function prototype
void display_results(); // function prototype
void search_for_student_studentID(); // function prototype
void search_for_student_by_name(); // function prototype
void delete_student(); // function prototype
void initialise_database(); // function prototype
void Run_statistics_for_individual_student(); // function prototype
void Run_statistics_for_all_student(); // function prototype
int linear_search(long); // function prototype
int linear_search_sname(char*); // function prototype


int main()
{

    initialise_database();  // call the function to set all free positions to 1

    for(;;)  // infinite loop
    {
        switch(menu())   // calling function menu within switch
        {
            case 1:
                add_student();  // calling function add_student
                break;
            case 2:
                delete_student();  // calling function delete_student
                break;
            case 3:
                display_students(); // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 4:
                search_for_student_studentID();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 5:
                search_for_student_by_name();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 6:
                Run_statistics_for_individual_student();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 7:
                Run_statistics_for_all_student();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 8:
                display_results();  // calling function display_students
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("Quitting Program\n");
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Invalid option chosen\n\n");
        }
    }  // end of infinite loop

    return 0;
}

void add_student()
{
    int freepos = -1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(BENG[i].free == 1)
        {
            freepos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(freepos != -1)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Enter student ID (8-digits): ");
            scanf("%ld%*c", &BENG[freepos].StudentID);
        }
        while(BENG[freepos].StudentID<10000000 || BENG[freepos].StudentID>99999999);

        printf("Enter firstname: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", BENG[freepos].fname);

        printf("Enter surname: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", BENG[freepos].sname);

        do
        {
            printf("Enter year of course (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d%*c", &BENG[freepos].year);
        }
        while(BENG[freepos].year < 1 || BENG[freepos].year > 4);

        printf("Enter course name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", BENG[freepos].course);

        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter result of semester 1  Module %d: ", j+1);
            scanf("%f%*c", &BENG[freepos].results_semester_1[j]);
        }
        for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            printf("Enter result of semester 2  Module %d: ", k+1);
            scanf("%f%*c", &BENG[freepos].results_semester_2[k]);
        }

        BENG[freepos].free = 0;  // mark record as taken
    }
    else
        printf("No position free at present\n");
}

void display_students()
{
    // output the values just entered
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
        {
            printf("Student ID: %ld:\n", BENG[i].StudentID);
            printf("Firstname: %s\n", BENG[i].fname);
            printf("Surname: %s\n", BENG[i].sname);
            printf("Year: %d\n", BENG[i].year);
            printf("Course: %s\n", BENG[i].course);
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_1[j]);
            }  // end of for
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_2[j]);
            }  // end of for
        }  // end of if
    }  // end of for
}
void display_results()
{
    // output the values just entered
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_1[j]);
            }  // end of for
            for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[i].results_semester_2[j]);
            }  // end of for
        }  // end of if
    }  // end of for
}
int menu()
{
    int choice;
    printf("1. To add a student\n");
    printf("2. To delete a student\n");
    printf("3. To display all students\n");
    printf("4. Find a student using studentID\n");
    printf("5. Find a student by student Surname\n");
    printf("6. Find student would you like to run statistics for\n");
    printf("7. Find statistics for all students\n");
    printf("8. Display results of all students\n");
    printf("9. Exit Program\n");

    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    while(choice < 1 || choice > 9);

    return choice;
}

void initialise_database()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) // set all structure variables free to 1
        BENG[i].free = 1;
}

void delete_student()
{
    long search = 0;
    int position = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of student to delete\n");
    scanf("%ld%*c",&search);

    position = linear_search(search);

    if ( position == -1 )
        printf("%ld is not present in array.\n", search);
    else
        printf("%ld is present at location %d.\n", search, position+1);
    BENG[position].free = 1;
    return;
}

void search_for_student_studentID()
{
    long search = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf ("Enter the number to search: ");
    scanf ("%ld%*c",&search);

    position = linear_search (search);

    if ( position == -1 )
        printf("%ld is not present in array.\n", search);
    else
        printf("%ld is present at location %d.\n", search, position+1);
    printf("Student ID: %ld:\n", BENG[position].StudentID);
    printf("Firstname: %s\n", BENG[position].fname);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", BENG[position].sname);
    printf("Year: %d\n", BENG[position].year);
    printf("Course: %s\n", BENG[position].course);

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1,         BENG[position].results_semester_1[j]);
    }

    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[position].results_semester_2[j]);
    }

    return;
}

void search_for_student_by_name (char *sname)
{
    int position = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Enter the surname of student to search\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", sname);

    position = linear_search_sname(sname);

    if ( position == 1 )
        printf("%s is not present in array.\n", sname);
    else
        printf("%s is present at location %d.\n", sname, position+1);
    printf("Student ID: %ld:\n", BENG[position].StudentID);
    printf("Firstname: %s\n", BENG[position].fname);
    printf("Surname: %s\n", BENG[position].sname);
    printf("Year: %d\n", BENG[position].year);
    printf("Course: %s\n", BENG[position].course);
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 1 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[position].results_semester_1[j]);
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        printf("Result semester 2 Module %d: %0.2f\n", j+1, BENG[position].results_semester_2[j]);
    }

    return;
}
int linear_search(long find)
{
    int c = 0;

    for ( c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++ )
        if (BENG[c].StudentID == find )
            return c;

    return -1;
}
int linear_search_sname(char *find)
{
    int c = 0;

    for ( c = 0 ; c < SIZE ; c++ )
        if (strcmp (BENG[c].sname, find) == 0 )
            return c;

    return -1;
}
void Run_statistics_for_individual_student()
{
    long search = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 100;
    float sums = 0,maxsums=0;

    printf("Enter the number to search\n");
    scanf("%ld",&search);
    printf("The statistics for student ID (%ld):\n",search);

    position = linear_search(search);

    if ( position == -1 )
        printf("%ld is not present in array.\n", search);
    else

        for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            sums += BENG[position].results_semester_1[i];
        }
    printf("Average grade over 6 subjects for this student in semester 1 is %0.2f marks\n",    sums/6);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        maxsums = BENG[position].results_semester_1[i];
    }
    if(maxsums>max)
    {
        max=maxsums;
    }   // end of if

    printf("Max grade for this student in semester 1 is %d\n", max);
    {

        for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            if(BENG[position].results_semester_1[k]<min)    
            {
                min=BENG[position].results_semester_1[k];
            }   // end of if    
        }// end of for
        printf("Min grade for this student in semester 2 is %d\n", min);    
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        sums += BENG[position].results_semester_2[i];           
    }
    printf("Average grade over 6 subjects for this student in semester 2 is %0.2f marks\n",  sums/6);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        maxsums = BENG[position].results_semester_2[i];  
    }   
    if(maxsums>max)     
    {
        max=maxsums;
    }   // end of if        

    printf("Max grade for this student in semester 2 is %d\n", max);    
    {

        for(k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        {
            if(BENG[position].results_semester_2[k]<min)    
            {
                min=BENG[position].results_semester_2[k];
            }   // end of if    
        }// end of for
        printf("Min grade for this student in semester 2 is %d\n", min);    
    }
    return ;
}

void Run_statistics_for_all_student()
{

    // output the values just entered
    int i,j,k, max,min=100;
    float sums,maxsums=0;
    {
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

            if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    {
                        sums += BENG[i].results_semester_1[i];              
                    } // end of for

                }  // end of for

            }  // end of if

        printf("Average grade for all students in semester 1 is %0.2f \n", sums/(SIZE*6)); 
    }               
    {
        for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)

            if(BENG[i].free == 0) // only print taken records
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    {
                        maxsums = BENG[i].results_semester_1[i];  
                    }   
                    if(maxsums>max)     
                    {
                        max=maxsums;
                    }       
                }// end of for
            }// end of if
    }
    printf("Max grade for all student in semester 1 is%d\n", max);  

    {
        for(k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)

            if(BENG[k].free == 0) // only print taken records
            {
                for(j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        if(BENG[i].results_semester_1[i]<min)   
                        {
                            min=BENG[i].results_semester_1[i];
                        }       
                    }// end of for
                }// end of for
            }// end of if
    }
    printf("Min grade for all student in semester 1 is %d\n", min);


    return ;
}
```

**Use/Output:**

```
./bin/student_database
1. To add a student
2. To delete a student
3. To display all students
4. Find a student using studentID
5. Find a student by student Surname
6. Find student would you like to run statistics for
7. Find statistics for all students
8. Display results of all students
9. Exit Program
1
Enter student ID (8-digits): 12345678
Enter firstname: Johnny
Enter surname: Walker
Enter year of course (1-4): 1
Enter course name: UnderwaterMusic
Enter result of semester 1  Module 1: 88.8
Enter result of semester 1  Module 2: 89.8
Enter result of semester 1  Module 3: 90.8
Enter result of semester 1  Module 4: 91.0
Enter result of semester 1  Module 5: 68.7
Enter result of semester 1  Module 6: 66.7
Enter result of semester 2  Module 1: 92.4
Enter result of semester 2  Module 2: 88.4
Enter result of semester 2  Module 3: 82.3
Enter result of semester 2  Module 4: 95.3
Enter result of semester 2  Module 5: 91.2
Enter result of semester 2  Module 6: 88.5
1. To add a student
2. To delete a student
3. To display all students
4. Find a student using studentID
5. Find a student by student Surname
6. Find student would you like to run statistics for
7. Find statistics for all students
8. Display results of all students
9. Exit Program
3
Student ID: 12345678:
Firstname: Johnny
Surname: Walker
Year: 1
Course: UnderwaterMusic
Result semester 1 Module 1: 88.80
Result semester 1 Module 2: 89.80
Result semester 1 Module 3: 90.80
Result semester 1 Module 4: 91.00
Result semester 1 Module 5: 68.70
Result semester 1 Module 6: 66.70
Result semester 2 Module 1: 92.40
Result semester 2 Module 2: 88.40
Result semester 2 Module 3: 82.30
Result semester 2 Module 4: 95.30
Result semester 2 Module 5: 91.20
Result semester 2 Module 6: 88.50
1. To add a student
2. To delete a student
3. To display all students
4. Find a student using studentID
5. Find a student by student Surname
6. Find student would you like to run statistics for
7. Find statistics for all students
8. Display results of all students
9. Exit Program
9
Quitting Program
```

**Additional Suggestions**

One suggestion I have for you is to not statically declare the string sizes in the function and just allocate as needed in `add_student` function. For example:

```
struct Student
{
    long StudentID;//works
    char *fname;//works
    char *sname;//does not work
    int year;//works
    char *course;//works
    float results_semester_1[6];//works
    float results_semester_2[6];//works
    int free;  // 1 means its free, 0 means its not
};
```

Then you could simply allow `scanf` to dynamically allocate memory as needed with for example:

```
scanf("%m[^\n]%*c", &BENG[freepos].fname);
```

Additionally, you will see I had to change all the `scanf` format strings in `add_student` to prevent a `newline` from remaining in the input buffer (the result of pressing [enter]) causing your program to **skip** over the next input. Controlling the state of the input buffer is critical. There are a number of ways to do this, but taking a careful look at `man scanf` is a good place to start.

Comment: Glad I could help. There is a LOT of code there. It isn't in that bad of shape, it will just take a little more time to dot all the `i`s and cross all the `t`s.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", dest);` scans nothing if the input is `'\n'` and that `'\n'` remains in `stdin` and leaves `dest` undefined.  Adding a width is useful `scanf("%20[^\n]%*c", ...);`

Comment: Now you've gone and done it -- again. Left me bewildered and scratching my head. How does specifying a `maximum field width` change the behavior of `scanf` in this instance? `\n` will still be left in the input buffer and `dest` will still be `undefined`? (`uninitialized` if not already) Obviously, I am missing something that makes this make sense. What is that something? (sigh, bewildered...)

Answer (score 0):

There's an error here

void search_for_student_by_name(sname)       // just write the type of sname

Comment: thanks for the replys guys there is probably loads of errors im really new to C ill fix those errors